# Android internal Storage error

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I am really new to android and writing a simple game for android. 
In the game, like in most games you have score, 
now, I want the score to be saved in Internal Storage, and for some reason, I manage to save the score, but not load it back. 
 
here is the code:

```
final TextView best = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.best);

public int read = -1;
public StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
public String scoreTxt = buffer.substring(0, buffer.indexOf(" ") + 1);
public int score = 0;
// Save
try {
    fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("record.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fileOutputStream.write(scoreString.getBytes());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if (fileOutputStream != null) {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save() works fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// load
try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("record.txt");
    while ((read = fileInputStream.read())!= -1){
        buffer.append((char)read);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
best.setText("Best: " + scoreTxt);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "load() is good too " +    scoreTxt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

when I run the app, there is no crash or anything special in the logcat, but when ever I use `scoreTxt` the output is nothing, just " ". 
can somebody help me solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You never assign scoreTxt a value in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `buffer` after it has being populated.Now when `scoreTxt` is initialized `buffer` is null

You need to replace this

```
 best.setText("Best: " + scoreTxt);
```

with

```
scoreTxt = buffer.substring(0, buffer.indexOf(" ") + 1);
best.setText("Best: " + scoreTxt);
```

Comment: I did it and it is still the same

Comment: buffer.substring(0, buffer.indexOf(" ") + 1);  this logic might be incorrect..please check

Answer (score 0):

In addition I wouldn't store game score into a file because score changes frequently and you want to avoid disk access a lot. Store it in SharedPreferences and from time to time flush it to a file on a background thread.